# Azure Storage Emulator error on creation of queue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-storage

Getting error on creation of cloudqueue. Using storage emulator in local machine.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 604
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.Create(QueueRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Queue\CloudQueue.cs:line 52
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.CreateIfNotExists(QueueRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Queue\CloudQueue.cs:line 176
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Name of the queue is `copyprojectqueue`

**Conclusion:** As Gaurav commented the older version of storage emulator was not supported in the latest library version.

Comment: What is the name of the queue you're using?

Comment: @GauravMantri `copyprojectqueue` is the name of the queue

Comment: Can you please tell the version of Storage Client library and the version of Storage Emulator.

Comment: The result of calling ToString on the StorageException contains additional information that is helpful for debugging issues such as these.

Comment: @MichaelRoberson-MSFT Thanks a lot, that really helped. \Gaurav was right indeed the older version of storage emulator was not supported in the lastest library version.

Answer (score 0):

According to 400 error, I assume that the [queue name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/naming-queues-and-metadata) is incorrect. The following is the snippet from the document.

> Every queue within an account must have a unique name. The queue name must be a valid DNS name, and cannot be changed once created. Queue names must confirm to the following rules:
>
> A queue name must start with a letter or number, and can only contain letters, numbers, and the dash (-) character.
>
> The first and last letters in the queue name must be alphanumeric. The dash (-) character cannot be the first or last character. Consecutive dash characters are not permitted in the queue name.
>
> All letters in a queue name must be **lowercase.**
>
> A queue name must be from 3 through 63 characters long.

Other related info:

[Azure Storage Naming Rules](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2014/06/12/azure-storage-naming-rules/)

Comment: The name of the queue is `copyprojectqueue`. I have been using the same name since last year, it has worked properly. However, now suddenly am faced with this error.